# Visual Studio 2013 C++ - Passing std::unique_ptr to a bound function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Using Visual Studio 2013 RC and C++, I'm trying to pass an `std::unique_ptr` to a function that has been bound using `std::bind`. However, I'm having trouble because VS doesn't seem to like it when I try this. Here's what I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void func(std::unique_ptr<int> arg)
{
    std::cout << *arg << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::function<void (std::unique_ptr<int>)> bound =
        std::bind(&func, std::placeholders::_1);

    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(42));
    bound(std::move(ptr));

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles in GCC 4.8.1, but not in VS2013 RC. I've always had problems with move semantics in VS, but I'd really like to use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr` or raw pointers.

One workaround I've found is to change the function signature to accept an `std::unique_ptr&`, which does compile in VS and GCC, but doesn't make the intent of `func` taking ownership of the `std::unique_ptr` particularly clear, and also prevents me from safely asynchronously calling the function unless I do something particularly ugly:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <string>

void func(std::unique_ptr<int>& arg)
{
    std::cout << *arg << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::function<void (std::unique_ptr<int>&)> bound =
        std::bind(&func, std::placeholders::_1);

    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(42));
    std::promise<void> prom;
    std::async(
        [&bound, &ptr, &prom]
        {
            std::unique_ptr<int> movedPtr = std::move(ptr);
            prom.set_value();

            bound(std::move(movedPtr));
        });

    prom.get_future().wait();

    // Wait here
    std::string dummy;
    std::cin >> dummy;
}
```

Is there a way to get around this without changing `func`'s signature?

Thanks!

Comment: you cannot pass unique_ptr by value, it doesn't have copy constructor.

Comment: Hence the `std::move()`. Calling `func(std::move(ptr))` works perfectly fine if I call it directly, but not when it's bound.

Comment: then why not change `func` to accept `unique_ptr<T>&&` instead

Comment: Because it doesn't compile in VS2013... Having the argument be `std::unique_ptr<T>` vs. `std::unique_ptr<T>&&` makes no practical difference whatsoever in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with VS 2012 recently. I believe this is a bug in MSVC; at least in MSVC++11 the pseudo-variadic expansion seems to forward the parameters by value to some internal function. Seems this hasn't been improved.
As a workaround, I'm using lambdas instead, but another hack is required to make it work:

```
std::function<void (std::unique_ptr<int>)> bound =
    [] (std::unique_ptr<int> arg) { func(std::move(arg)); };
```

still doesn't compile. But if you add any captured value (even one that isn't used), it compiles:

```
int x;
std::function<void (std::unique_ptr<int>)> bound =
    [x] (std::unique_ptr<int> arg) { func(std::move(arg)); };
```

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I need! It should be easy to ifdef out for Linux targets as well. Thank you so much!

Comment: You just saved me a redesign effort. Thanks. I know that GCC 4.7 handles placeholders properly as well.

Comment: The hack with the fake captured value is no longer required in VS 2013 (VC12).

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the parameter into the bound call to `func` also.  Not only in the invocation of `bound`

```
bound(std::move(ptr));
```

but also in the binding:

```
std::function<void(std::unique_ptr<int>)> bound =
    std::bind(func,
              std::bind(std::move<std::unique_ptr<int>&>,
                        std::placeholders::_1));
```

This is compiling in VS2013 (update 4) for me.

Answer (score 0):

Functions bound with `std::bind` do not forward arguments, it copies them to the function. As a result, `std::bind` doesn't work with move-only types as of c++11. This problem is the idea behind proposals for "more perfect forwarding" ([like this one](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3466.html)).  There's a newer one, but I can't seem to find it right now.

Comment: That may be true for functions which have arguments bound into the `std::function`, but the `std::function` I'm trying to use has only placeholders. My first code snippet compiles in GCC, but not VS. I'm trying to find a workaround so I can keep `func`'s signature and still compile with VS.