# Need to use shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, callback, smart-pointers

I have two classes: Lattice and ModelGUI. I want to pass function from Lattice to GUI as a callback. I implemented Lattice as unique_ptr. Some code:

ModelGUI.h:

```
using CheckTypeClbk = std::function<Enums::AgentType(int)>;
ModelGUI(const Matrix* matrix_, CheckTypeClbk callback, float windowHeight_, float windowWidth_, float latticeWidth_);
```

main.cpp:

```
std::unique_ptr<ILattice> lattice(new Lattice(5, qMap));
ModelGUI gui(lattice->getLattice(), std::bind(&ILattice::checkAgentType, lattice, std::placeholders::_1),
800, 1200, 800);
```

With this implementation I got strange compilation errors about templates:

```
1>main.cpp
1>d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\xutility(390): error C2664: 'std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<ILattice,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::_Ph<1>>::tuple(std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::_Ph<1>> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<ILattice,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'std::allocator_arg_t'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=ILattice
1>        ]
1>d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\xutility(389): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\functional(1902): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Compressed_pair<Enums::AgentType (__cdecl ILattice::* )(int),std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<ILattice,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::_Ph<1>>,false>::_Compressed_pair<Enums::AgentType(__cdecl ILattice::* )(int),_Cv_TiD&,const std::_Ph<1>&>(std::_One_then_variadic_args_t,_Other1 &&,_Cv_TiD &,const std::_Ph<1> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=ILattice,
1>            _Cv_TiD=std::unique_ptr<ILattice,std::default_delete<ILattice>>,
1>            _Other1=Enums::AgentType (__cdecl ILattice::* )(int)
1>        ]
1>d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\functional(1903): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Compressed_pair<Enums::AgentType (__cdecl ILattice::* )(int),std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<ILattice,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::_Ph<1>>,false>::_Compressed_pair<Enums::AgentType(__cdecl ILattice::* )(int),_Cv_TiD&,const std::_Ph<1>&>(std::_One_then_variadic_args_t,_Other1 &&,_Cv_TiD &,const std::_Ph<1> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=ILattice,
1>            _Cv_TiD=std::unique_ptr<ILattice,std::default_delete<ILattice>>,
1>            _Other1=Enums::AgentType (__cdecl ILattice::* )(int)
1>        ]
1>d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\functional(1902): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,Enums::AgentType (__cdecl ILattice::* )(int),std::unique_ptr<ILattice,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &,const std::_Ph<1> &>::_Binder(_Fx &&,std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &,const std::_Ph<1> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=ILattice,
1>            _Fx=Enums::AgentType (__cdecl ILattice::* )(int)
1>        ]
1>d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\functional(1929): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,Enums::AgentType (__cdecl ILattice::* )(int),std::unique_ptr<ILattice,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &,const std::_Ph<1> &>::_Binder(_Fx &&,std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &,const std::_Ph<1> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=ILattice,
1>            _Fx=Enums::AgentType (__cdecl ILattice::* )(int)
1>        ]
1>d:\predator-prey\predator-prey\main.cpp(16): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,Enums::AgentType (__cdecl ILattice::* )(int),std::unique_ptr<ILattice,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &,const std::_Ph<1> &>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=ILattice
1>        ]
```

But when I am using shared_ptr instead of unique_ptr, everything works fine. Is a good practice? I've heard to avoid shared_ptr as much as I can, unless they are totally necessary.

Comment: The thing with a `unique_ptr` is there can be only one. You can't copy them. You can't pass them around without transferring ownership. You have to decide who is the rightful owner of the pointer. Only if `lattice` and `gui` both have a legitimate stake should you use a `shared_ptr`. In this case it looks like `lattice` has a wider scope than `gui` and can safely maintain ownership and you can provide a raw pointer to `gui`. Sidenote: Instead of `std::bind`, consider using a lambda expression.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::bind`?

Comment: `std::bind` is generally slower and more cumbersome than a lambda, and many find the lambda syntax cleaner.

Comment: Since I had to grind this out for a comment to the answer, here's what that simplified version would look like with a lambda: https://ideone.com/ErgtSi . Note the `unique_ptr` `t`  is being passed by reference. Do not allow `f2` to outlive `t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Do you need `shared_ptr`?

No. At least not for the given example.

If `lattice` and `gui` are defined in different scopes with different lifespans and being used all over the place, wowie-zowie, we can talk about `shared_ptr`.

## Why?

Let's start with a really simple example that shows why `unique_ptr` is causing grief.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct test
{
    test() = default;
    test(const test &)
    {
        std::cout << "copied" << std::endl;
    }
    void func(int i)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    test t;
    std::function<void(int)> f1 = std::bind(&test::func, t, std::placeholders::_1);
    f1(1);
}
```

`test` doesn't do much other than tell us when the object is copied and prove that the function ran. Executing it we'll see that [`t` is copied and produced the expected output from the function](https://ideone.com/8A13Z4).

`std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied because that would pretty much ruin the whole *unique* part of the job description. We see that if we change `main` a little to use a `unique_ptr` and get a little closer to the question as posed.

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<test> tp = std::make_unique<test>();
    std::function<void(int)> f1 = std::bind(&test::func, tp, std::placeholders::_1);
}
```

[As expected, this doesn't compile.](https://ideone.com/s0lMFn) We can make this compile by using a [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

```
std::function<void(int)> f1 = std::bind(&test::func, std::reference_wrapper<std::unique_ptr<test>>(tp), std::placeholders::_1);
```

or provide a raw pointer to `bind`

```
std::function<void(int)> f1 = std::bind(&test::func, tp.get(), std::placeholders::_1);    f1(1);
```

but this requires `tp` to have wider scope and be guaranteed to outlive `f1`. What this really comes down to is why use more than `test t;` in the first place? Do we really need a pointer here at all?

But let's go with it for now because we can at least make this look a lot prettier before we head off to greener pastures. Here is the same thing with a lambda expression

```
std::function<void(int)> f1 = [&tp](int i) { tp->func(i); };
```

Normally I'm not a champion of "Lambda is easier to read than `bind`," but this case is a pretty convincing argument.

Getting back to basics,  it's not really all that different from

```
int main()
{
    test t;
    std::function<void(int)> f1 = [&t](int i) { t.func(i); };
    f1(1);
}
```

and completely eliminates the pointer. No pointer, no `shared_ptr`.

If `t` can be fire and forget, the only user is the callback, let the lambda carry around a copy of `t` and let the original die.

```
std::function<void(int)> scopedemo()
{
    test t;
    return [t](int i) mutable { t.func(i); }; //
}

int main()
{
    auto f1 = scopedemo();
    f1(1);

}
```

Note the `mutable`. Lambda defaults to carrying around constants and can't be used to invoke non-`const` methods or be used as a non-`const` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

- You are passing `std::unique_ptr` by value and it's always a bad [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905487/how-can-i-pass-stdunique-ptr-into-a-function), because it doesn't have a copy constructor.
- Why doesn't your code even compile? It seems that passing std::unique_ptr to a bound function is a long-living [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308754/visual-studio-2013-c-passing-stdunique-ptr-to-a-bound-function) of visual studio.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. The question raised in your second point is answered by the first point.

Comment: Nope, these two points are mostly ortogonal. Because this code compiles in gcc and clang, BUT fails exactly in vs2012+.

Comment: `std::bind` takes its arguments by value. That forces a copy. `unique_ptr` cannot be copied. [Error results.](https://ideone.com/fOVt45)